# how to write on a partition that I previously lock (using Delphi)

Tags: delphi, locking

I want to lock a partition, write a few files using TFileStream and then unlock it.
I found how to lock and unlock but I don't know how to write.
So far my code is:

```
Const
   FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME = $00090018;
   FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME = $0009001C;

var HLockedVol: THandle;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function LockDrive(Drive: AnsiChar): Boolean;
var
   OldMode: UINT;
   BytesReturned: Cardinal;
begin
   Result := False;

   OldMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
   try
      HLockedVol := CreateFile(PChar(Format('\\.\%s:', [AnsiLowerCase(string(Drive))])), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil,
         OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
      if HLockedVol <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      begin
         Result := DeviceIoControl(HLockedVol, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, nil, 0, nil, 0, BytesReturned, nil);
      end;
   finally
      SetErrorMode(OldMode);
   end;
end;

function UnlockDrive: Boolean;
var
   OldMode: UINT;
   BytesReturned: Cardinal;
begin
   Result := False;

   OldMode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
   try
      if HLockedVol <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      begin
         try
            Result := DeviceIoControl(HLockedVol, FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME, nil, 0, nil, 0, BytesReturned, nil);
         finally
            CloseHandle(HLockedVol);
         end;
      end;
   finally
      SetErrorMode(OldMode);
   end;
end;
```

I'm suppose to use HLockedVol, but I don't know how...

Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of locking the volume in order to just write a couple of files? You need to open the volume when you want to perform low-level reading or writing of the partition (or the volume) on sector level rather than on file level.

Comment: You don't even appear to have locked it - you will allow others to open handles to it whilst your handle is still open.

Comment: To Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp: My application fails if some other application or Windows is writing in the same time. To David Heffernan: I have test it on a USB stick/key and I can't access it in a File Manager or write on it. But if what you say it's true please show me a better way to lock it.

Comment: @John well I may be mis-reading the MSDN documentation, but `FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE` grants read and write access to others. However, since you are opening an entire volume, then this point may be moot. Perhaps if you open a volume then that locks it completely, I don't know. Also, if you want us to read your messages, use @David and @Eugene - that way we get notifications of our messages.

Comment: @David: Yes, you're right, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE grants read/write access. I will change them if you think it will help. But the main issue is still not solved: how do I write (preferably using TFileStream)...?

Comment: @John If you want to use TFileStream, then why are you locking the entire volume and opening a handle to the device? How are you going to write a file? You have opened the device at sector level?

Comment: The documentation for `FSCtl_Lock_Volume` says that `File_Share_Read` and `File_Share_Write` are required. Don't worry about whether that *really* allows the volume to be shared — locking the volume requires there to be no open files on the drive anyway.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I hadn't hauled in the `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` bit which I can now see is where the actual locking occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You've opened something and received a file handle. To write to it, use [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747.aspx). You can wrap the handle inside a [`THandleStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.THandleStream) if you're more comfortable with streams.

Note that when you do this, you are not writing *files*. You're writing directly to the disk, *below* the level of abstraction where such a concept as "file" exists. And you can't do I/O on any normal files in the meantime (because you locked the volume).

Although this is an answer to the question you asked, it's probably not a solution to your problem. I invite you to post a new question describing your problem; don't worry about the solution you're currently pursuing right now.

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to use that handle, but, like you said, I'm not writing normal files. Before I post a new question I will describe here for what I need: my friends asked me to make a program who fills the entire free space on a USB stick/key/hdd with a dummy file. This way is protected against most viruses. But sometimes I get writing error because some other program (or OS) is writing on it.

Comment: @John How are you going to find the free space? Once you start writing on this HANDLE you will corrupt the file system. If you want to fill the free space, just create a file and start writing to it until the system says that you can't write any more.

Comment: @David I have an Api function for this: GetDiskFreeSpaceEx. I knew that writing on that Handle will corrupt the file system, that's why I asked this question. For Fat16/Fat32 maybe your idea will work (losing the display on progressbar), but I'll definitely lose the speed of creating files on NTFS. You can check the program and its sources on: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?laa7zo7cj82njca

Comment: @John Well, that's not the question you asked! Why will writing a normal file using the standard API calls `CreateFile` and `WriteFile`, perhaps via `TFileStream`, be slow on NTFS?  I suggest you re-group and perhaps ask a different question once you are a bit clearer on what it is you want to know.

Comment: @David Yes, it's not 100%, but you can't say it's below 75%. I'm using a superfast way of writing dummy files on NTFS (not hack) and is not working when you are writing in the file (with any function). And I'm 100% clear of what I want to know but my bad english and the fact that I'm not used with this site are not helping me.... Please have a look at my program, test it and then will talk.

Comment: @John Sorry, but I don't want to look at your program.

Comment: @David I don't understand why, but it's your right. But in this case you'll not understand 100% why I asked this question, why I don't agree with you 100%. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @John Well, I have other things to do, and debugging other people's code doesn't figure too highly, sorry.

Comment: @David I understand that but I'm not asking you to debug my code. In that link it's the exe to see how it's working. I added the sources in the eventuality that someone will want to see them, it's not mandatory.

Comment: Ok, like many suggested, I will ask a new question. But I'm not sure how different it will be...

Comment: John, here you asked *how* to write. The answer is to use `WriteFile`. If you wanted to ask *what* to write, then you should have said so. I thought you either already knew what file-system data you wanted to write to the volume, or you didn't understand that you'd have to write file-system data in the first place. Your next question should either ask what to write to keep the file system valid, or else just ask how to quickly fill up a USB drive. If you already have some way to do that, but it fails, include it in your question.

Comment: @Rob I said in my first phrase: "I want to lock a partition, write a few files using TFileStream and then unlock it". So when I asked "how to write" it was about those files (normal files). I knew that using that handle will get me nowhere but I asked here in the eventuality that someone knows a better way. And, since the program will not be used on my stick/key/hdd I won't use methods that may damage their data. I know already how to fill a USB drive.