# how to prevent that the OS or other programs writes on a storage device in the same time as my program does

Tags: delphi, locking

I'm a Delphi programmer.
I want to fill the entire free space of a storage device with dummy file(s).
During this operation I want to prevent that Windows or other programs write on the device.
I know it is doable because I have seen programs that do it.

I already have the code to create the dummy files (using TFileStream, very fast on NTFS) so all I need is some sort of lock/unlock code.

Does someone know a way..?
Thank you for any suggestion.

I will accept even solutions that will change the way I create those files, provided that the entire program will work better.

Thank you.

Best regards, John.

Comment: When you unlock the device what is to stop someone freeing up the space on the drive?

Comment: And why do you need to lock? Why don't you just write until the system reports an out of disk space error? At that point you know that you have filled it.

Comment: "I know it is doable because I have seen programs that do it." -- I don't know that what you seem to be asking is possible. What exactly have you seen other programs do?

Comment: @David, Of course, this is possible, but if I can't make a perfect program (which nobody can do) that means stop developing this program..? For your second comment: I already replyed a few times why: the main reason is that the program needs to be fast and to minimize writing operations on sticks. @ChrisW For example I used programs for backup that locks the drive before the operation, even if they write simple files.

Comment: @ChrisW Well, I can't be 100% sure that is "lock" in every case. But it seems that way: I can't access the drive anymore. Some programs even use the word "lock".

Comment: @John Have you considered getting an anti virus program? For example MSE is free and very good.

Comment: @David I already have one. But the program is not just for me. And I don't understand what is the connection with my question.

Comment: @John In your previous question, you said you wanted to fill your disk so defend against viruses

Comment: @David Yes, but: 1. it's easier to prevent infection than to treat it; even if I disinfect the files on stick in some cases they will not work fine. 2. An anti virus  program that protect 100% against viruses doesn't exist. 3. It's easy to fill the free space. In conclusion I think that this program is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which is presumably transactional (i.e. it either succeeds or fails), which I think (I haven't tested/checked it) you can use to grow a file to fill available space.

Comment: this is a far better answer than mine!

Comment: Yes, I know it, it's kind of using "try TFileStream.Size := Size; Result := True; except  Result := False; end". One of the problems is that you have to "guess" the new size. And during this you have to try many values + meantime the OS or the other program can write to USB drive again.

Comment: @john slow down for a minute! This is how file systems work. They can be modified. Even if you can lock somehow what is to stop another app deleting your dummy file once you unlock? Can you answer that?

Comment: @David, Of course, nothing. That's true. But what are the chances that another app "sees"that file and "thinks" that is a good idea to delete it? It's the user that decides how to use the programs on his computer and all I can do is to make sure that all goes well in areas where he doesn't have direct control.

Comment: @John Mirror - there's also a "FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME Control Code" e.g. documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364575(v=VS.85).aspx which may be relevent to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I know it also, I use it in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661504/how-to-write-on-a-partition-that-i-previously-lock-using-delphi . But I was advised to ask another question...

Comment: @John Mirror - I don't know: I'm just looking ay the documentation. I don't see a way to write to a file using a volume handle. How about the FSCTL_SHRINK_VOLUME Control Code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964912(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @ChrisW Thank you for trying to help me. I really appreciate this. But unfortunately I don't think that FSCTL_SHRINK_VOLUME will help...

Comment: @John Mirror - I don't know whether what you want is possible: a backup program which locks the volume doesn't need to create new files on the volume while it's locked.